# Why is there extra minus sign in Feynman's rules for every closed fermionic loop?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions, grassmann-numbers

I know this is connected to the fact that fermions are represented by anticommuting operators, but I still cannot find the way to get this minus in Feynman rules.

Comment: This is explained on Wikipedia, under "Feynman diagram".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because a fermion loop with $N$ vertices along the loop corresponds to, up to bosonic factors everywhere (which never change the sign and mostly commute with everything else),
$$ D =  \langle \psi_1^\dagger \psi_1\cdot \psi_2^\dagger \psi_2 \cdots \psi_N^\dagger \psi_N \rangle $$
where each of the products $\psi^\dagger \psi$ comes from one vertex. Note that vertices are what produces the $\psi$ factors because they appear in the interaction Hamiltonian. However, in the Feynman rules, we need to revisualize the diagram so that it's composed from propagators which are factors of the type $\psi_1\psi_2^\dagger$ and so on, geometrically corresponding to links between adjacent vertices. We can make this form manifest if we move $\psi_1^\dagger$ to the very end:
$$ D = - \langle \psi_1\psi_2^\dagger\cdot \psi_2 \psi_3^\dagger \cdots \psi_N \psi_1^\dagger\rangle $$
In this form, we have a product of $N$ nice factors $\psi_i \psi_{i+1}^\dagger$ that may be attributed to propagators. However, I had to add a minus sign because we needed to permute Grassmann-valued $\psi_1$ through $2N-1$ other fermionic operators and $2N-1$ is odd. Therefore I had to correct the sign by $(-1)^{2N-1}=-1$ for both expressions to be equal.

I was a bit schematic so I didn't indicate whether I used an operator formalism or the Feynman path integral approach. The logic for the sign is the same in both versions. In the Feynman path integral language, the $\psi$ objects in the demonstration above are Grassmann numbers, not operators, so they strictly anticommute with each other.

Comment: Hi @Luboš , I posted a question related to this one  [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308700/sign-of-feynman-diagram-with-single-propagator-closed-loop?noredirect=1#comment694331_308700). Could you try answering it if you have the time?

Comment: I am sorry, @user2582713 - but as far as I can see, your question isn't just "related". It's identical. Why don't you think that my answer above answers your question as well?

Comment: Hi Professor, may I ask a question here? $\psi_1$ and $\psi_1^\dagger$ are of same spacetime index, so I think these two fields don't anti-commute. If we change their order, there should be an infinity term caused by $\delta$ function. Would this be right?

Comment: Dear Daren, first, whether two fields commute or not commute cannot be determined just from their having the "same indices". In generally, the nonzero commutator is between a field F and its canonical momentum - the derivative of the Lagrangian density with respect to the time derivative of the field F. Moreover, psi1 and psi1 dagger only have trivially the same index because they are full Dirac spinors. But if you had a Weyl spinor, its Hermitian conjugate would transform differently under the Lorentz group - the opposite chirality!

Comment: Now, yes, the commutator of the field and its Dirac conjugate is the delta-function of the 3-position, a c-number (a trivial operator proportional to the identity operator). Indeed, the terms coming from this anticommutator (fermionic case here) is what contributes all the terms with the propagators in the Feynman  diagrams, and this is also discussed in this question. You must be careful what the order is, and I was careful! If you wrote another expression with a random permutation, you would have to add or subtract another term from the anticommutator you mention.