# Sign of Feynman diagram with single-propagator closed loop

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams

On p94 of Fetter & Walecka's *Quantum Theory Of Many Particle Systems*, it is stated that since propagators with both arguments at the same time such as $G^0_{\alpha\beta}(x, x)$ arise from contractions of field operators in the 2-body potential, which always appear in the order $\psi^\dagger_\beta(x)\psi_\alpha(x)$ i.e. [adjoint]$\cdot$[non-adjoint], the contraction should be interpreted as

$$
\begin{split}iG^0_{\alpha\beta}(x,x) & = \lim_{t'\rightarrow t^+}\left<\Phi_0|T\left[\psi_\alpha(\vec{x}t)\psi^\dagger_\beta(\vec{x}t')\right]|\Phi_0\right>\\
& = -\left<\Phi_0|\psi^\dagger_\beta(\vec{x}t')\psi_\alpha(\vec{x}t)|\Phi_0\right>
\end{split}$$
whose field operator order matches that above. However, p98 says that the factor of $(-1)^{N_{\mathrm{closed\space loops}}}$ multiplying each diagram is only incurred once the field operators contracted in the loop are rearranged so that each pair is ordered $\psi_\alpha(x)\psi^\dagger_\beta(x)$ [non-adjoint]$\cdot$[adjoint]. This seems like a discrepancy to me. Can someone explain?

Comment: Is T is the time ordering operator? Does it spit out -1's too?

Comment: Hi. Yeah - for fermionic field operators it does. But the text says that we should only interpret the propagator in this way once we've reordered the pairs to be [non-adjoint][adjoint], which is what is confusing me. This might help http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/448/Fetter%20Walecka.pdf

Comment: Hmm I found some text stating that you could reorder the fields an even amount of times to get them in a certain order. F is related to the number of loops it says. It looks like it is related to the parity of the permutation to me.

Comment: Maybe cycles of the permutation?

Comment: I am sorry, @user2582713 - I voted it was a duplicate and my 1 vote apparently was enough to close this question which I didn't expect. Why is it exactly that even though you found the original question, you decided that your question is any different? The first line of your displayed equations is a definition of $G$. The minus sign on the second line appears because the time-ordering operator (by its definition) must be equipped by a minus sign for each transposition of fermionic fields' ordering. And the loops arise because of the reasons I explained in my answer to the original question.

Comment: Again, the minus sign comes from each loop because to get the standard form, one must permute the last (or first) fermionic factor through the chain that contains an odd number of fermionic fields. There are two ways how the fermionic couples may be ordered. Simply taking the power of a Hamiltonian for fermions gives you $\psi_1(x)\psi^\dagger_1(x)\cdot \psi_2(y)\psi^\dagger_2(y) ...$ where the neighbors have the same $x$. But to convert it to the Feynman diagram with propagators, you must pair them at different points.

Comment: So you need the factors like $\psi_1^\dagger(x)\psi_2(y)\cdot \psi_2^\dagger(y)\psi_3(z)\dots $ In this form, the pairs may be recognized as the form for the propagator, but to achieve this form, you must move the first $\psi_1(x)$ at the end. This corresponds to an odd number of fermi-fermi transposition which is why you get a minus sign for each fermionic loop (loop in the required permutation of the points at which bilinear operator in fermions sits).

Comment: On page 98 there are superscripts on the G's... I wonder if the time ordering operators are hiding inside those G's.

Comment: Hi @LubošMotl . Thanks for your response. I think I'm confused about why we don't interpret $G$ with $t'\rightarrow t^{-}$ so that the field operator order stays $\psi\psi^{\dagger}$ instead of $\psi^{\dagger}\psi$ after application of the time-ordering operator.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking, what is $t^-$ in your latest question, and why you talk about the simple permutation of $\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger$ at all. This transposition is completely trivial and aside from the anticommutator, it just produces a minus sign. But the single pair of $\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger$ is not enough to understand where the minus sign from fermionic loops comes from, so if you're  limited by thinking about at most two different fermionic operators in a product, you can never understand things like the fermionic loop minus sign.

Comment: The sign from the fermionic loops comes from an odd permutation of $2N$ fermionic operators in a product that is needed to switch from the pairing in which the $\psi^\dagger,\psi$ at the same point are neighbors; to the ordering where the couples are made out of $\psi(x)$ and $\psi^\dagger(y)$ at different points.

Comment: When I said $t^{-}$ in my last comment, I was referring to the text I mentioned: Fetter & Walecka. Sorry that I didn't make that clear. On page 94, it says that propagators whose time arguments are equal should be interpreted like $G^{0}_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{x}t,\vec{x}t)=\lim_{t'\rightarrow t^+}G^{0}_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{x}t,\vec{x}t')$  so that the time-ordering operator in the expression for $G^{0}$ ends up swapping the field operators to give $-\left<\Phi_0|\psi^\dagger_\beta(\vec{x}t')\psi_\alpha(\vec{x}t)|\Phi_0\right>$ and the field operator order is now...

Comment: ...the same as how they originally appear in the interaction Hamiltonian. I think my real question is why $G^{0}_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{x}t,\vec{x}t)$ is not interpreted as $\lim_{t'\rightarrow t^-}G^{0}_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{x}t, \vec{x}t')$ instead, so that we end up with $+\left<\Phi_0|\psi_\alpha(\vec{x}t)\psi^\dagger_\beta(\vec{x}t')|\Phi_0\right>$ and the field operators now have the order we produce in order to justify the minus sign for the closed loop.